# Issues with running Python script from command line using venv and pyenv

Tags: python, zsh, python-venv

I created a basic python script which calls an API among other things. Within the directory I also created a virtual environment:

`python -m venv venv`

I've been running the script is VS Code no problem, and have it pointing to `./venv/bin/python`.

I want to set this up so it repeats using a cron job. However, I've tried running the below command...

`/Users/aaron/project/venv/bin/python /Users/aaron/project/extract_starling.py`

...and get this error:

```
 File "/Users/aaron/project/extract_starling.py", line 9, in <module>
    account_id = config['starling_config']['account_id']
  File "/Users/aaron/.pyenv/versions/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/configparser.py", line 963, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'starling_config'
```

Should note that when I run `which python` when not pointing at a virtual environment, I get this...

`/Users/aaron/.pyenv/versions/miniforge3/bin/python`

I setup `pyenv` a while, although don't know why it's saying `miniforge`.

Anyway, I'm wondering if someone could assist, as not quite sure what's going on here.

EDIT:

Should also note that my script is importing the `configparser` module, with a `config.conf` file in the same directory, if that's relevant. This is the first part of my script:

```
import requests 
import configparser
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Config data for Starling
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.conf')
account_id = config['starling_config']['account_id']
```

Output from `pyenv global`

`3.9.1`

Output from `python --version`

`3.9.7`

Output from `pyenv local`

`no local version configured`

Output from `pyenv versions`

```
  system
  3.10.0
  3.6.15
  3.8.10
* 3.9.1 (set by /Users/aaron/.pyenv/version)
  miniforge3
  miniforge3/envs/tf
```

Comment: Please show output of `pyenv global`,  `pyenv local`, `pyenv versions` and `python --version`

Comment: @SUTerliakov Just updated question with output. Not sure whey python version is different from pyenv global

Comment: Huh, first of all - could you try to activate your venv (`source <env path>/bin/activate`) before running python command? It prevents you from typing full path every time, plus sometimes helps to avoid such problems.

Comment: Still the same issue. If I `cd` into the `project` directory then run the command it works fine.

Comment: Maybe this is my mistake. But when reading the config file with `configparser`, it works when I give the full path to the file. I sort of expected it to work by just giving the name of the file, since it's in the same directory.

Comment: @AaronWright It would find it if your current working directory (CWD) in your shell is where the file is, but not if if'ts in the same directory as the script.

Comment: @Keith yes think that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Think this was my own fault.

In my script, I replaced

`config.read('config.conf`)`

with

```
import os
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
config.read(f'{cwd}/config.conf')
```

And it worked.
Basically providing the full path rather than the relative path.